# I want to send email through my ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created web form, and now I want this data to be stored in the database and form be emailed to the email. This is not working, because it consistently tells me that there is a Server error in '/' Application. Even though I redirect to Thankyou page, and also I have included code for Thank you page. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Nordstromapp.Models;

    public SupportController(){
        _db = new NordstromEntities();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Form/[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var categoryList = new SelectList(new[] {"How the Site Looks",
            "Product Offered", "How the site works", "General Comment"});
        ViewBag.CategoryList = categoryList;


        var concernList = new SelectList(new[] {"Shoes", "Handbags and accessories", "Beauty and Fragrance", "Sales", 
                                "Designe Collection", 
                                "Kids and Babies' collection", "Home gifts", "Service", "Other"});
        ViewBag.ConcernList = concernList;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Models.Support support)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(support.Question))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Question", "Question is required");
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            // save to the database
            return Redirect("Thankyou.cshtml");
        }
            return Create();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
@model Nordstromapp.Models.Support

@{

var Question = Request["Question"];
var First_name = Request["First_name"];
var Last_name = Request["Last_name"];
var Telephone_number = Request["Telephone_number"];
var Email = Request["Email"];
var errorMessage = "";
var debuggingFlag = false;
try {
    // Initialize WebMail helper
    WebMail.SmtpServer = "localhost";
    WebMail.SmtpPort = 21;
    WebMail.UserName = "";
    WebMail.Password = "";
    WebMail.From = "";

    // Send email
    WebMail.Send(to: Email,
        subject: "Help request from" + First_name,
        body: Question
    );
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    errorMessage = ex.Message;
}}

<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Request for Assistance</title></head><br><body><br><p>Sorry to hear that you are having trouble, Mr/Ms <b>@Last_name</b>.</p>
@if(errorMessage == ""){<p>An email message has been sent to our customer service
     department regarding the following problem:</p><p><b>@Question</b></p>}
else{<p><b>The email was <em>not</em> sent.</b></p>
    <p>Please check that the code in the ProcessRequest page has correct settings for the SMTP server name, a user name, 
       a password, and a "from" address. </p>
    if(debuggingFlag){
        <p>The following error was reported:</p><p><em>@errorMessage</em></p> }  } </body>
```

Comment: Does it tell you what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right off the bat I see a couple issues with the way you end your action.

1. You should be doing a `return RedirectToAction("Create")` at the end or a simple `return View()` so you can display model errors (if you add the helpers to your view or a validationsummary block).
2. You should not redirect to a .chstml page directly. Instead either `return View("ThankYou")` or, better yet, redirect to a Get action that displays that page. (This is the Post, Redirect, Get pattern to avoid issues of re-POSTing data if a user refreshes the page.)